# Stack overflow in C++ destructor

Tags: c++, stack-overflow, destructor

I try to create the detor and got a "Stack Overflow"
I know why but I want that its work...

```
#include <iostream>
#include "printTreeToFile.h"
#include "BSNode.h"
#define _BS BSNode::
#define _BSNode _BS BSNode
_BS ~BSNode()
{
    Del(this);
}
void _BS Del(BSNode *x,int y)
{
    if (x->isLeaf())
    {
        delete x;
        return;
    }
    if (x->_Right != NULL)
        Del(x->_Right,y += 1);
    if (x->_Left != NULL)
        Del(x->_Left,y += 1);
    if (y != 1)
    {
        delete x;
    }
    return;
}
```

i try to do that as recursive but the delete call to Del so 
we got unlimited loop

Comment: `#define _BS BSNode::`
`#define _BSNode _BS BSNode`
-- Arrgh! That _hurts_!

Comment: Destructor calls `Del()`. `delete x` invokes destructor, which again invokes `Del()`.

Comment: @RegevZafrani There's a good reason for `BSNode::`. With the `#define` you are obfuscating the fact that `Del` is a method of `class BSNode`. And C++ is obfuscated enough by itself without any help. And the solution is: Don't `delete this` from the destructor, because, well, that's what is already happening when the destructor is called.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
_BS ~BSNode()
{
    Del(this);
}

void _BS Del(BSNode *x,int y)
{
    if (x->isLeaf())
    {
        delete x;
        return;
    }
    if (x->_Right != NULL)
        Del(x->_Right,y += 1);
    if (x->_Left != NULL)
        Del(x->_Left,y += 1);
    if (y != 1)
    {
        delete x;
    }
    return;
}
```

You're deleting `this` recursively. You don't need all this. You're over-thinking. All you need is:

```
BSNode::~BSNode()
{
    delete _Left;
    delete _Right;
}
```

That will automatically recurse down the left and right subtrees, and stop at nulls.

Comment: @RegevZafrani And this is how to write a destructor for a binary tree node. Do you understand that `delete` calls the destructor? I suggest you try it before you debate this further.

Comment: `delete` already checks for `null` before it does anything else, as others have already said, and as you should already know. You don't need to parrot what I've already written. I'm not interested in debating this further until you've tried it.

Comment: Do you understand why? Step through it if you don't.

Answer (score 1):

By calling `delete x`, you are calling the destructor of the node while you are in a function called the destructor of the node. There is no need to destroy the actual object in a destructor.

Comment: I say again...
I know what is my error but i dont know how to fix it

Comment: "There is no need to destroy the actual object in a destructor." - Just leave out the `delete x` and move the `Del` function to the actual destructor.

Answer (score 0):

The destructor is a function that allows an object to release the resources it owns. The destruction of the object itself:

- is done automatically if the object was allocated on the stack and your code exit the block of its declaration.
- is explicitely done via the delete keyword by the calling code.
- and some more (see § 12.4.10 from [N3242](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf))

What you are trying to do here, is to delete the object itself from its owd destructor. By doing so, your call to delete on this will trigger a call to the destructor which itself call its destructor.

The solution to your problem is to destroy only the resources the BSNode object owns (probably _Right and _Left). If the sub-nodes have no value, then the destruction chain will stop.

> invoking delete on a null pointer has no effect (see § 12.4.12 from [N3242](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf))

In your case, simply do this:

```
void _BS Del(BSNode *x)
{
    delete _Right;
    delete _Left
}
```

Sorry I don't understand why the 'y' variable was introduced in your code.